# Issue at starting JIRA WAR instance with Apache Tomcat 7 and PostgreSQL 9.3.4

Tags: tomcat7, jira

i'm currently trying to setup a JIRA portal using Tomcat 7 and PSQL.

```
**OS Version**
root@DevJira~ $lsb_release -d
**Description:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

**JAVA VERSION**
root@DevJira~ $java -version
**java version "1.8.0_05"**
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

**PSQL VERSION**
root@DevJira~ $psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4
```

When i try to get into my localhost/jira, i receive the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /jira

type Status report

message /jira

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
```

The catalina.log shows:

```
Jun 09, 2014 8:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/jira.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jira]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 09, 2014 8:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Jun 09, 2014 8:20:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 09, 2014 8:20:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1584 ms
```

Any further information you might need, please let me know.

Comment: I doubt that this is related to the Tomcat deployment problem above, but you should be aware that the current version of JIRA [only officially supports Java 7](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA062/Supported+Platforms).

Comment: Look in the other logs for the details of what went wrong with the deployment and add that information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, as what Scott mentioned above, you will need Java 7 at most to run JIRA. All Atlassian products are not built for Java 8 deployment yet. Just setup Java 7, and ensure that the `$JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to Java 7.

Then, rebuilt the WAR file as per the KB from Atlassian: [JIRA WAR Fails to Start Due to Invalid or Unreadable WAR File](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/JIRA+WAR+Fails+to+Start+Due+to+Invalid+or+Unreadable+WAR+File)